# Piping executable stdout into websocket

Tags: websocket, ide

I am trying to build a web based IDE with a capability of compiling sources in a browser. The issue I am dealing with how to get compiler like gcc or c++ running in a web browser. The idea is compiler is running on server and its output is sent to client using websocket. I've been looking into libs like Socket.IO however I am not sure how to pipe stdout of a binary executable into websocket. Any ideas or approaches?

Comment: what language / framework are you using in the backend ?

Comment: The frontend part is developed in Angular, backend in Spring Framework however the use of java or specific framework is not a requirement

Answer (score 0):

I have found a github project called [websocketd](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd) that does exactly what I wanted. However I settled on another solution. Thanks anyway :-D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).